# Figuring out $x^n$

Tags: exponentiation

Exponents are used to represent multiplying by a number over and over. but big numbers, like $6^8$ are hard to calculate. is there any simple way to calculate big numbers of the form $x^y$?  ($y>0$ and is whole)

Comment: I think english speakers say "integer" for something in $\mathbb{N}$. Did you get "whole" on google translate ?

Comment: @Vincent: Actually English speakers say "integer" for something in  $\mathbb Z$. Of course $\mathbb N\subset\mathbb Z$, so formally you are right. More to the point, also the term "whole number" is somethimes used in English text, as explained [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whole_number) (see the end of the second paragraph).

Comment: Given that "calculating" those numbers usually just means to bring them into a certain form which is then considered "the" result, one way to calculate that number is to just declare that decimal numbers are not special, and therefore you can just write $6^8$ in base $6$, which gives $100\,000\,000$ :-)

Comment: @Vincent "Whole number" is a common phrase for integer but mostly used by non-mathematicians.  It is rare in serious mathematics.  I think "whole" in this context without the following "number" is less common.  So, "$2/3$ is not a whole number" sounds quite natural to me but "$3/2$ is not whole" sounds less natural.  P.S. I am a native speaker born in London.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One classic way is iterated squaring. Start with 1.

1. Write the exponent in binary form
2. Loop over digits starting with most significant-1:

   - if 1: multiply with x
   - if 0: don't multiply with x
3. Square the number, go to next digit and iterate 2 until we run out of digits.

Let's take example $9 = (1001)_2$

We start with most significant 1 bit:

1. it is 1, so we multiply with x, we now have $x$
2. new iteration, so we square, and we have $x^2$
3. digit nr 2 is 0, so we just square $(x^2)^2=x^4$
4. digit nr 3 is 0, so we just square $(x^4)^2 = x^8$
5. last digit is 1 so we multiply with x: $x(x^8) = x^9$

Comment: I'd love an example of this so I don't have to think too much. :D

Comment: Yes I don't like thinking too much. Math should not be about that nasty thinking business.

Comment: Ok, let me rephrase. I don't quite get what 'Loop over digits means.' Edit, never mind. I'll look up 'iterated squaring.'

Comment: @Arby ok i made an example.

Comment: thanks for the extra effort. Sorry I was a bit lazy.

Comment: Don't apologize to me for your lazyness. Apologize to future-you.

Comment: Your insults say more about you than about me.

Comment: How could you possibly interpret that as an insult?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57395/discussion-between-arby-and-mathreadler).

Answer (score 1):

One short cut is to notice that $x^4 = (x^2)^2$ so it can be done with two multiplications rather than the obvious 3.  The savings get bigger for higher powers $x^{16} = (((x^2)^2)^2)^2$ - four multiplications instead of 15.  In those simple examples, the power is itself a power of 2 but you can do things such as $x^{17} = x(((x^2)^2)^2)^2$.  Expressing $y$ in binary can help you plot an efficient combination of squaring and multiplying by $x$.

Comment: interesting! i actually study binary, so these answers are going to be useful!

Comment: @AlexanderDay Write out some numbers in binary.  Then try to find the most efficient calculation in my style and compare them.  You should see a pattern. Depending on the relative cost of multiplication and division, you could consider overshooting and coming back. E.g. $x^{15}$ as $x(x(xx^2)^2)^2$ or $(((x^2)^2)^2)^2 / 2$.  6 multiplications v 4 multiplications and 1 division.